# iOS UICollectionReusableView is on top of scroll indicator

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When i set a background color to my headerView the scroll indicator is behind it, looking super weird.
I created a sample project [here](https://github.com/ivangodfather/Funcook/raw/master/TestHeader.zip) but its basically a simply project with a collectionView registering a suplementaryView for a header with a background.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this in `UICollectionView` `delegate` method `willDisplaySupplementaryView`

`view.layer.zPosition`  to zero

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        if (elementKind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
            view.layer.zPosition = 0
        }
    }
```